# Vertically alligned divs to horizontal when in responsive mode

Tags: html, responsive, display

So, currently, I have three buttons down one side and when I reduce the screen size, they stay there, after flexing and putting fixed widths on them. [Here is the CodePen](http://codepen.io/Carolinelf/pen/WpNgxE), if anyone could have a look for what I am missing.

I have this for now which I thought would work:

```
.buttons {
    width: 100%;
}
.button-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;

}
.button-strip img {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Still very new to all of this :)

Answer (score 0):

Some images aren't showing up on the CodePen you linked, but here's what I worked out, perhaps it's what you're looking for:

```
.button-strip {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;  /* Stop them from breaking lines */
}
.button-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;  /* Not really required, but I thought it looked best centered */
}
```

This is what it looks like to me, so hopefully I could still manage to help you

[image: Screenshot]